# Toggle plus minus signs in BS 4.x Card Header

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to learn Bootstrap. I have the code referenced below. The problems are:

1-When the card is expanded, I wanted the plus sign to change to a minus sign but this is not happening. How to fix this? I want not to use a separate js function at the end of the body.

2-An odd square appears when I used the code below, when "fas" is used instead of fa, the square is gone. I assume that 'fas' is for the free set and since I had no subscription, then this cause the square to appear. Is this correct?

```
onclick="$('#collapseOne').toggleClass('fa-fa-minus-square fa-plus-square')"
```

jsfiddle containing the code:
[Problem Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/aq9Laaew/253083/)

[image]

Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few small errors/typos, on line 9 in HTML id="#collapseOne" it should be id="collapseOne" and not good classes of Font awesome class names on line 8 in HTML.

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
      <div class="card mb-0">
         <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
            <a class="card-title"
               onclick="$('#collapseOneSquare').toggleClass('fas fa fa-minus-square fas fa fa-plus-square')">
             <i class="fas fa fa-plus-square fa-pull-right p-1" id="collapseOneSquare"></i>
              Card Header Text
            </a>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseOne" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <p>XXXXXXXXX Contents XXXXXXXXXX</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent observations. I really need a way to check this kind of code, as in regular programming languages. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NoChance it happens, beacuse of rush or being tired, take it slow :)

Comment: You are really correct, there is too much to learn for 1 brain! I appreciate your comment.